# how we make ckeditor dialog non resizable ,non draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am creating a new plugin named small image repository system for CKEditor. and i m quite successful to make it. but i got an issue that dialog height increase automatically when i load set of images automatically.so please suggest me how i make CKEditor non draggable and non resizable?

I already tried the code to make non resize dialog for CKEditor which is given below:

```
resizable : CKEDITOR.DIALOG_RESIZE_NONE
```

But still i didn't solve my problem please help me

Answer (score 1):

```html
CKEDITOR.dialog.add('plugin_name', function (editor){
                var id = editor.id;
                return {
                    minWidth: 820,
                    minHeight: 400,
                    resizable : CKEDITOR.DIALOG_RESIZE_NONE,////resize disble
                    contents:
                    [
                        {
                            id: 'iframe',
                            expand: true,
                            elements:
                                [
                                   {

                                       type: 'html',
                                       html: '<div style="width:820px;height:400px"><iframe src="' + CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath('foot_notes') + 'dialogs/test.html" frameborder="0" name="iframeinsert' + id + '" id="iframeinsert' + id + '" allowtransparency="1" style="width:820px;height:400px;margin:0;padding:0; resize: none;" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>'
                                   }
                                ]
                        }

                    ],
                };
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the dialog's `resizable` property to `CKEDITOR.DIALOG_RESIZE_NONE` is only going to prevent users from changing the size of the dialog window. Btw, `CKEDITOR.DIALOG_RESIZE_NONE` is the default so there's no need to set it explicitly in your dialog definition. You can find CKEditor's documentation page on the subject [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition).

It sounds like what you need to do is set the `height` property. This will set the height of the dialog to the value you assign to it, in pixels.

Cheers!